# How can we update a table row using updatepanel?

Tags: ajax

i am using linkbutton in aspx page so  when click on link button open the one of the table row based on  id like  tr1.so row propertieslike  id is tr1 and visible=false,runat=server.so i am using ajax update panel. getting error at updatepanel

Comment: what have u tried and what error are u getting? post the code that u tried.

Comment: what error in which line? on what code?

Comment: i am using linkbutton in aspx page so when click on link button open the one of the table row based on id<tr id="tr1" runat="server" visible="false">
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">
<Triggers><asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList6" />
</Triggers><ContentTemplate><td>
</td><td align="center">
<asp:Image ID="Image6" Height="20" Width="20" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/description-icon.gif"/>
</td></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: Error Line No:607             Line 605:                </tr>
Line 606:                <tr id="tr1" runat="server" visible="false">
Line 607:                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">
Line 608:                        <Triggers>
Line 609:                            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList6" />

Comment: please edit the question and paste the code there...no one will be able to understand this

Comment: can you edit your question with your code and error in format @cherry?